# SMD SOT89 identification

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image]

I am trying to Identify this SMD component, Pin 1 GND , 2-VCC, 3-? Out I can identify top letter is C , Bottom is G11, I think it might be a transistor but it odd being connected to the main power rail. Part is from bremshey bike monitor. Unfortunately  other identification is blocked out because it's burned out. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's labeled 'U4', so it's an IC not a transistor. My guess would be a linear voltage regulator of some sort. You can see that transistors are labeled with a Q, as there's a big Q5 over to the left.

Comment: good point, to the left is a 3.3V LDO what type of IC would have the label Cxx G11?

Comment: ON the PCB it says CHANG YOW SM6665-K01 I tried to find the schematic but it's hard to find,

Comment: It looks like old Rotamola silkscreen before Laser marking was used.  Looks like centre pin is 0V

Comment: So why the marking of G11? if it's not a transistor?

Comment: Every Mfg has their own markings  , it could be Philips  (obsolete)

Comment: Can you trace the output, via eye or poke with multimeter and find out what’s connected downstream? My bet it’s an LDO.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, It turned out to be an LDO 5.0V the way I solved it was I replaced it with a 3.3. LDO and it worked but the display was very dim. I figured the next one up would be a 5V regulator, so I desoldered one from another PCB put it on and it works like a charm. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I agree. no idea,

but if one of the junctions isn't shorted determine if it PNP or NPN with a DMM then choose a 1W transistor that makes sense for V*I

You can always use a bigger part not SMD with higher Vceo.

e.g. linked to switch Motor in regenerator mode 80V? then 100mA,  low V switch? then 30V 500mA

e.g. NPN  2SD1463  , PNP 2SB1045    (100V 50mA)

At least it is not an LDO like U7.
What event triggered the failure?

Comment: yes I saw this but I don't think DTB113ZKA is a SOT89 package, According to the PCB Pin 1 is GND and Pin 2 is VCC, Pin 3= Vout I guess, If it's a Digital Transistor why would it be connected to the main VCC?

Comment: Does the C mean "Collector?"

Comment: not normally marked... probably part of other markings burnt out

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't determine if it's PNP or NPN because each pin is an open. Any ideas to determine the original C B E pins?

Comment: Is there a way to test this without replacing the part? Eg if pin 1 was GND and 2 was VCC then could I just put a jumper from pin 2 to 3, if it's acting like a switch?

Comment: Shorting can cascade failures, what function died?

Comment: The display does not light up eg. no power, but I tested the backlight of the display and it's fine, just looks like this component. I agree that it's a LDO , could I swap it for a 3.3V LDO and see what happens?

Comment: I would check input voltage 1st displays need more than 3.3 and too much may damage it.  Maybe try a 30mA drop Resistor e.g. 12V /30m=400 Ohms and check voltage rise and sign of life. The centre pin looks like 0V  so 12V drop with 50mA= 600mW which a 1W LDO can handle. But you dont know yet if this was a 2ndary failure or primary

Comment: how about using a POT then turning it up slowly to see if the display comes to life.

Comment: too much Pd to dump in a pot

Comment: I would expect 0.5W min